# Updating a variable in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have done some researching on this topic but everything I have tried doesn't work properly.  I just want to add a counter to certain aspects of my batch file.  The count.txt file contains:

```
Counters started on 2-18-15
opened: 0
actions: 0
```

The script that I have written so far is:

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    for /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%r in (`findstr opened: counter.txt`) do (
    echo %%r
    set opened=%%r
    set /a opened=!opened!+1
    echo opened= !opened!
    )
```

I would like to just edit the number of opened times and not change anything else in the file.  I know this is rememdial but I am still very remedial in my batch abilities.

I have specified ! in place of %, using some debugging it is pulling the correct variable and adding 1 to it, the current issue is that it is not saving over that variable afterwards.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable assignment problem in DOS batch file for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650146/variable-assignment-problem-in-dos-batch-file-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delayed expansion to properly display variables set inside of code blocks.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=2" %%r in (`findstr /C:"opened:" counter.txt`) do (
    set opened=%%r
    set /a opened=!opened!+1
    echo opened=!opened!
)
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that I already had setlocal enableddelayedexpansion specified at the top of the file.  I have modified my script to exactly what you wrote but it is still not updating.  The counter.txt file looks exactly the same afterwards

Comment: Is my script setup to properly write to the .txt file at the same location that it is pulling from?

Comment: @Konan - I just noticed that `findstr` wasn't being called correctly. I've edited the code. Also, if counter.txt isn't in the same directory as the batch script, you'll have to include the full path in the for loop.

Comment: Thank you @SomethingDark.  I just edited it also it is pulling the correct info, adding +1 but not overwriting or even saving to the file afterwards. I think the error must be in my last line where it is suppose to write to the file.

Comment: I did implement your new changes, it is still not writing to the .txt file and updating the value.  That seems to be the only issue now.

Comment: Well, no, it's not going to write to the file if there's no output redirect anywhere. You need the `>` symbol to overwrite the contents of the text file or `>>` to add to the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

You never write the information back to the file - you are simply echoing the value to the screen.

Batch does not have a mechanism to modify a value in a file directly. You must write a new file with the updated information, and then replace the old file with the new.

Assuming the order of the lines does not matter, I would write a batch script as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=2" %%N in ('findstr /bc:"opened: " counter.txt') do set /a opened=%%N+1
>counter.txt.new (
  findstr /vbc:"opened: " counter.txt
  echo opened: %opened%
)
move /y counter.txt.new counter.txt >nul
```

After running the script once, your counter.txt file would look like:

```
Counters started on 2-18-15
actions: 0
opened: 1
```

You might want to preserve the order of the rows. You could do so with a pure batch script, but I rarely use batch to modify text files. Instead, I would use my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - it is faster, more reliable, and simpler (assuming you understand regular expressions and rudimentary JScript)

```
call jrepl "^(opened:\s*)(\d+)$" "$1+(Number($2)+1)" /j /f test.txt /o -
```

Comment: I tried using jrep1, I copied the source code to my own jrep1.bat file and then implemented the call command and change the file name to counter.txt.  It did not properly update the counter variable. I most likely didn't do something right with it!  I did use the first code you posted that rebuilds the file each time it is opened and it is working properly.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
for /F "delims=" %%a in (q28585447.txt) do (
 for /F "tokens=1,2" %%q in ("%%a") do (
  IF "%%q"=="opened:" (CALL :REPLACE %%r) ELSE (ECHO %%a)
)
)
)>newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:REPLACE
SET /a newvalue=%1+1
ECHO(opened: %newvalue%
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q28585447.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt To replace your file, use `move /y newfile.txt q28585447.txt` (after modifying throughout for your filename, of course.

Simply, it reads each line from the data file to `%%a` then tokenises `%%a` using the default separators into `%%q` and `%%r` If `%%q` is the target string, then `%%r` contains the value to be incremented, otherwise regurgitate the line in `%%a`.

The subroutine `:replace` simlpy adds 1 to the parameter passed and reconstructs the target line.

By surrounding the entire `for...%%a` loop in parentheses and redirecting to a file, all of the output `echo`ed is redirected to that file.